# 4-momentum of massless photons

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics, photons, momentum

The time component of a particle's 4-momentum is

$$ E'=\frac{E-up}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}\tag{1}     $$

Now suppose it is photons that you are observing from a system moving at $u$ on a line towards the source (assume that the $u$ and $p$ are on one line for the rest). As is experimentally known, the energy of the photons that you measure depends on how fast you are moving. (or how fast the source is moving)

So one should get different values for $E$ and $E'$ which is the Doppler effect.

The following are true for massless photons:

$$  E=hf$$
$$   p=E/c $$

Now if I substitute in (1) $E$ divided by $c$ for the momentum, I do not get the correct relativistic Doppler effect equation which is,

$$ f'=f\sqrt{\frac{c-u}{c+u}} \tag{2}$$

It is not clear to me why when I substitute $E$ times $c$ for the momentum, I do get (2). But $p$ doesn't equal $Ec$.

Any thoughts on this matter?

Comment: Please use LaTex to format your equations so that others can read them more easily.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Comment: This is no homework assignment nor anything similiar.

Comment: Greetings! Please don't vandalize a question by substantially changing it after it has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You start with  $$ E' = \frac{E-up}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}} = \\ \frac{E-up}{\sqrt{(1-u/c)(1+u/c)}}.  $$

You know that $p = \frac{E}{c}$, so   $$ \frac{E-uE/c}{\sqrt{(1-u/c)(1+u/c)}} = \\ \frac{E(1-u/c)}{\sqrt{(1-u/c)(1+u/c)}} = \\ \frac{E\sqrt{1-u/c}}{\sqrt{1+u/c}} = \frac{E\sqrt{c-u}}{\sqrt{c+u}},  $$

now using $E = hf$,

$$ f' = f\sqrt{\frac{c-u}{c+u}}. $$

So yes your equations are consistent.

Comment: Wait, my original energy equation is incorrect if the units are not chosen such that c equals 1. (Eq1) In the numerator the term \(up\) has to be divided by \(c^2\) so I edited it. Then it does not come out right.

Comment: no, there is no $c^2$ in your equation. You can see it because it would be dimensionally incorrect: $[E] = [p][v] \neq [p][v]^{-1}$.

You are getting confused with the transformation for the momentum, $$p'_x = \frac{p_x - vE/c^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}} $$

Comment: I thought that it is called the time component because the transformation is of the same form as time's itself, only momentum switched for postion and energy for time. I would say it is even implied in FLP vol I chapter 17 so that is what confused me. But I agree with you on the dimensions.

Comment: It is the same transformation as the time components, i.e. the same Lorentz matrix $\Lambda$, if you take the appropriate 4-vector: $ (ct, x, y, z)$ and $(E/c, p_x, p_y, p_z)$.